# Recursively counting nested tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a document format with `<section>` tags that can be infinitely nested.  Each section contains things like paragraphs and tables, etc. but it's possible for the first element of a new section to be anything, including another section.

```
<doc>
  <section name="one">
    <p> Some text about <i>this</i> section.</p>
    <section name="one.one">
      <section name="one.one.one">
        <p>Other text</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</doc>
```

I'm converting the document format to markdown.  It seems the natural way to apply most tags would be with a structure like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="doc|p">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
    <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, with `<section>` tags I need to keep track of the nesting depth to construct the section name.  It seems like the natural way to do that is with `<xsl:call-template>` and `<xsl:param>`.

```
<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:param name="depth" select="1"/>
  <!-- do stuff to write the section name -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
</xsl>
```

The problem I have is that this needs to be triggered with `<xsl:call-template>` rather than `<xsl:apply-templates>` in order to increment the param.

```
<xsl:call-template name="section">
  <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I can't give a parameter to `apply-templates`, but neither can I just start the `section` (or `doc`) template with a recursive `call-template` either, because a new section may not be the first tag.

Is there some way to approach this that lets me use `call-template`, but maintains the tag order that xslt would normally follow with just the simple `apply-templates` tag?

Comment: Have you considered using [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number) to determine the depth? If you add an example of what the desired output should be, I'm sure someone can give you an example.

Comment: I hadn't considered it, but having looked, `xsl:number` seems to count the sequence of a tag rather than the depth.  I don't see how it could apply, however what I'm trying to accomplish is to produce standard markdown sections, prepending the section name with a number of '#' marks depending on the depth of the current section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number) (with `level="multiple"`) to determine the depth. This will give you something like `1.1.1.` (third level) but then you can translate the `.` to `#` (and the numbers to nothing).

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <section name="one">
        <p> Some text about <i>this</i> section.</p>
        <section name="one.one">
            <section name="one.one.one">
                <p>Other text</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="chars" select="'.0123456789'"/>

  <xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('_',.,'_')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:variable name="depth">
      <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($depth,$chars,'#')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
#one
 Some text about _this_ section.
##one.one
###one.one.one
Other text
```

**EDIT**

Here's another way counting ancestor-or-self like Michael Kay suggested (duh!)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('_',.,'_')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::section">#</xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah.. creative solution.  I hadn't thought of translating the `xsl:number` output to reduce the number of characters.  Unfortunately, that breaks down if there are 10 or more sections at any level.

Comment: @mpounsett - I updated my stylesheet. Instead of translating the digits, I translate the `.` and add one extra `#`.

Comment: @mpounsett - Sorry. Updated again to set the format to `1.` and then you don't have to worry about adding the extra `#`.

Comment: Aha!  That works perfectly.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @mpounsett - You're very welcome. Michael Kay is right though, it would be much easier to count ancestors. I always jump to `xsl:number` when I see count in a question. Not sure why I didn't think of it before. I'll add an example of that way too.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can pass params with apply-templates just as easily as with call-template: apply-templates allows an xsl:with-param child element.

Secondly, you don't need parameters to determine the depth of nesting because you can use XPath expressions that navigate upwards, e.g. `count(ancestor::section)`.

Comment: +1. You're absolutely right, it would be much better to loop over ancestors. I should've slowed down and thought about it for a minute lol. I added an example to my answer.